# Auto-completing Lookup Columns for Datasheet View and Allowing Multiple Values

Tags: 2010, lookup-column

I have a user that fills out their list most of the time in Datasheet view for quick data entry. They have a lookup column for single values only where they can just start typing in the name they're looking for and tab over when the entry is what they're looking for. They were hoping to have another column that would act in a similar manner but also allow multiple values - such as using a semicolon delimiter between names. I've tried using 3rd party solution options like:

https://autocompletelookup.codeplex.com/

Which didn't seem to work at all (Javascript errors when trying to use it as advertised), but also didn't seem to support datasheet view (made the column read-only unless you clicked to add a new item) but did support multiple values by using semicolon delimiters.

They just don't like the design of the multi-value column now where you have to scroll through entries to check all the check-boxes that apply.

Does anyone have an idea on how to make this work or if this is even possible?

**EDIT**: It would seem that the user had used the wrong type of column when following the author's example for implementing the look-up field which probably caused the JavaScript errors that I had mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what errors you see after deploying this codeplex solution developed by me. Anyways, answering your question; custom fields derived from SPLookup Field are not editable in datasheet view.

Comment: I checked with how the user was following the example you provided on codeplex and they used a choice column type instead of a Yes/No column type and were trying to use True/False in the values which is probably why the JS error occurred. I had revoked and removed the solution before I thought about taking a screenshot of the error. I suppose if there's no way to edit the custom-type lookup fields in datasheet view, this user is out of luck. Thank you for the information Nadeem.